# Need help trying to get Tabulator data to regularly update from Google Sheets

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, web-applications, tabulator

I have a table built with tabulator that pulls data from a Google Sheet. Here is how the table is built:

This function from a .gs file gets the data as an array that tabulator can work with for the table:

```
function getFinalsSheet() {
        const lstrow = findLastRow();
        const ws = ssd.getSheetByName("Final Date");
        const dataRange = ws.getRange(1, 1, lstrow, 14);
        const data = dataRange.getDisplayValues();
        const headers = data.shift();
        const fsData = data.map((r) => {
            const tempObject = {};
            headers.forEach((header, i) => {
                tempObject[header] = r[i];
            });
            return tempObject;
        });
        console.log(fsData);
        return fsData;
    }
```

This function pulls the data from the .gs file:

```
function finalsLoad(){
    google.script.run
    .withSuccessHandler(afterFinalsLoaded)
    .withFailureHandler((er) => {
     console.log("This Broke It")
})
   .getFinalsSheet() 
 }
```

This is where the table starts

```
function afterFinalsLoaded(fsData) {
         const table = new Tabulator("#due2-date-table", {
         ...
         ...
```

And this is the event listener that loads everything into the HTML page:

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded",startLoading)
function startLoading(){
 finalsLoad();
 }
```

My goal is for the data on the sheet to also update on the table without needing to refresh the page. I can add a variable into the function that places all the data on to the table and then include the table.updateData() to consistently update the data like this:

```
function afterFinalsLoaded(fsData) {
    const newData = finalsLoad();
    const table = new Tabulator("#due2-date-table", {
    ...
    table.updateData(newData)
```

The problem with this approach is that it will run the function over and over again until and spit out an error each time until there is a change in the data. Otherwise it would be perfect!

I've tried setting `finalsLoad()`, `table.updateData()`, and `getFinalsSheet()` into intervals to help reduce the number of times they run. None of them seem to really do anything and will instead just spit out new errors while still running every second. I think I got lost in the code so I'm not sure where the interval should even be placed.

Where do I need to add an interval to keep the data updated?

Comment: You will need to poll for the data from the clientside.  You could used setInterval

Comment: On the failureHandler try `withFailureHandler(er =>   console.log("This Broke It"))`

Comment: @Cooper I should have mentioned that only the first function is on a .gs file. The rest are on the HTML file. I've also tried using setInterval on `finalsLoad` function and it continues to spit errors and while ignoring the interval.

Comment: Yeah it was clear to me that `getFinalsSheet`  is a gs function but you will have to poll for the data from the html file

Comment: If I understood correctly, what Cooper meant was using `setInterval(function, milliseconds)` on `document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded",startLoading)
function startLoading(){
 finalsLoad();
 }`

Comment: @Cooper Oh my bad. Misunderstood what you were saying. The failureHandler change you suggested did make things nicer, but polling the data keep resetting the table, even when using `table.replaceData()`. Tabulator documentation states it should silently replace data without updating the scroll position.

Comment: @DiegoSanchez Tried that and now it's resetting the table at each interval. I also tried using`table.replaceData()` and it did the same thing. It just keeps resetting the table without passing on the new data array.

Comment: Sidenote: The documentation isn't even hosted on a secure site(http`s`), which really means that the author doesn't care about security. I wouldn't trust a library from such a author on my site.